# Fano variety $F_{1}(Q)$ of lines on smooth $3$-dimensional Quadric $Q$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Q \subset \mathbb{P}^4$ be a smooth three-dimensional quadric over $k= \mathbb{C}$ and $F_{1,3}:= F_1(Q) \subset \mathbb{G}(1,4)$ the Fano variety of lines on $Q$. (Note that since all smooth quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^n$ over $\mathbb{C}$  are isomorphic, we can
omit the $Q$ and write $F_{d,m}$ for the Fano variety $F_d(Q)$ of $d$-planes in a smooth $m$-dimensional quadric $Q$)

In [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/229327)  there is given a reference for the proof/exercise of the fact (?) that $F_{1,3}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Taking a closer look at this exercise from Harris' book *[Algebraic Geometry](http://www.springer.com/it/book/9780387977164)*, Exercise 22.6 page 290 the answer is refering to I noticed that the exercise and suggested "route" to solve is faulty and I would like to understand how to make the proof hints/step reasonable. Here the exercise:

> Exercise 22.6. Let $V$ be a four-dimensional vector space over $K$ and $\Omega: V \times V \to K $
> a nondegenerate skew-symmetric bilinear pairing. Show that the set $Q$ of two dimensional
> isotropic linear subspaces of $V$ is a subvariety of the Grassmannian
> $G(2,4) = \mathbb{G}(1, 3)$, and that it is isomorphic to a smooth quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^4$.
> Show that for every point $p \in \mathbb{P}V \cong \mathbb{P}^3$ the variety of isotropic subspaces containing $p$ is a line in $Q$, and that conversely every line in $Q$ is of this form for a unique
> point $p$. Conclude that $F_{1,3} \cong \mathbb{P}^3$.

There are several points I not understand in this exercise and it's relation with the original statement that $F_{1,3}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^3$. Firstly recall that in general a quadric $Q \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ comes as the zero locus of a homogeneous quadratic polynomial $Q: K^{n+1} \to K$, which may be thought of as the
quadratic form associated to a bilinear form

$$  Q_0: K^{n+1} \times K^{n+1} \to K $$

Therefore it seems that in this exercise the dimension of $V$ is one less than one wants to consider, indeed for $\mathbb{P}V \cong \mathbb{P}^4$ and therefore $V$ must be $5$-dimensional.

Moreover I not understand why $\Omega$ "represents" $Q$?
Why is $\Omega$ is considered to be *skew-symmetric*? This would imply that the associated quadric $Q$ is the whole space as every vector with respect a skew-symmetric is ansotropic, i.e. $Q(v)=\Omega(v,v)=0$.

Then it seems that during the exercise the spaces $F_{1,3}$ and $F_{1,2}$ (the later $F_{1,2}= F_1(\tilde{Q}) \subset \mathbb{G}(1,3)$ is the Fano variety of lines of $2$-dimensional(!) quadric $\tilde{Q} \subset \mathbb{P}^3 $) are confused frequently, making it hard what we are going to prove.
Note that is well known fact that $F_{1,2}$ is isomorphic to two disjoint copies of $\mathbb{P}^1$.

And then why should it be isomorphic to a smooth quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^4$. And moreover why should this exericse prove the stated claim in the beginning that $F_{1,3}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^3$?

Even if we assume that all written before are just typos and we indeed dealing with <s>four</s> five dimensional $V$ with <s>skew-symmetric</s> symmetric bilinear map $\Omega: V \times V \to K$ and consider $F_{1,3}$ living inside   $G(2,5)=\mathbb{G}(1, 4)$ (and **not** $G(2,4)=\mathbb{G}(1, 3)$ as stated in the text), *why* should $F_{1,3}$ be isomorphic to a smooth quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^4$?

Even having repaired all this, the rest of the exercise also not make any sense, since the the rest of the execise makes again use the space $\mathbb{P}V \cong \mathbb{P}^3$ of wrong dimension it order to establish the isomorphism we are looking for.

Question: How to "repair" the exercise in order to make the "guide" to solve this excercise reasonable in the way that the intermediate conclusion that $F_{1,3}$ isomorphic to a smooth quadric hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^4$ not looks like "fallen suddenly from heaven" and finally conclude that $F_{1,3} \cong \mathbb{P}^3$ with this rather "elementary" methods? Or do I missing the idea of this exercise?

Comment: The exercise is absolutely correct, read it more carefully.

Comment: @Sasha: but then I not see what I'm missing? At which point I'm missing 
the issue? Here the first points which already seemingly 
contradict to the assumption that we are working with 
$Q \subset \mathbb{P}^4$ smooth quadric hyperplace with the 
ultimate goal is to show $F_1(Q)\cong \mathbb{P}^3$:

Comment: **(A)** it is expected that $\Omega$ induces $Q$ in the way 
I explaned it in the question as $Q(v)=\Omega(v,v)$ 
& then passing to projectivization, right? But then 
there is a dimension problem, since passing to projective
space reduces dimension by $1$
**(B)** The Fano variety $F_1(Q)$ lives in 
$G(2,5)=\mathbb{G}(1, 4)$, the exercise works with 
$G(2,4)=\mathbb{G}(1, 3)$

Comment: Noone is saying that the quadric is contained in $\mathbb{P}(V)$, it is said, that the quadric lies in the Grassmannian $\mathrm{Gr}(2,V)$, which itself sits in $\mathbb{P}(\wedge^2V) = \mathbb{P}^5$; in fact it is a hyperplane section of the Grassmannian, and thus it sits in $\mathbb{P}^4$.

Comment: @Sasha: I see, so $V$ (resp $\mathbb{P}V$) is here introduced just as
"auxilary space" and so is a priori unrelated to $\mathbb{P}^4$
containing $Q$ by assumption, right? And then one shows that
$Q \subset \mathrm{Gr}(2,V) \subset \mathbb{P}(\wedge^2V) = \mathbb{P}^5$ 
is given as pullback of a hyperplane $H \cong \mathbb{P}^4$
to $\mathrm{Gr}(2,V)$, that's the $4$-plane one is looking for.

Comment: But why is it true that this subvariety of codimension $1$ 
(as in this case) of $G(2,V)$ can be obtained as pullback of
a *hyperplane*? For sure as long as the spaces a "nice" and 
over $\mathbb{C}$ we can argue similar to topology that 
for the closed immersions $V \subset W \subset \mathbb{P}^m$ there
exist a closed subvariety $Z \subset \mathbb{P}^m$ with
$V= W \cap Z$ (neglecting some schematic issues...). But you claim
something stronger, namely that $Z$ is a **linear** subspace. Why 
this holds here? It seems that is not suffice only to know that $Q \subset G(2,V)$ is

Comment: codim one subvariety, it seemingly matters here in certain sense "how" it is embedded, right? But then is it possible to make a statement similar to that one for Veronese embeddings, that says that only subvars $D_d \subset \mathbb{P}^1$ of degree $d$ are obtained as pullbacks of linear spaces under Verones embedding?

Comment: You need to analize what does it mean for a subspace of $V$ to be isotropic.

Comment: so here it seems to have something to do with explicit structure of isotropics
(I have to think a bit about it in detail) but does this give rise for a more
general characterization for subvarieties of general Grassmanian vartieties (at first 
only as "varieties) to come from pullbacks of hyperplanes under Plucker
embeddings? 


Namely something like a subvariety $X \subset G(k,n) $ is pullback 
of a linear hyperplane under Plücker iff blabla...?

Comment: As I said I have to elaborate first it in detail what is going on in $G(2,V)$ 
with $2-d$ isotropics and but it's interesting if it can be generalized to 
arbitrary $0< k \le n$ and give a honest criterion...

Comment: An update: so far I haven't done a mistake somewhere the picture perfectly fits together: The pullbacks of linear relations (=hyperplanes) on $\mathbb{P}^N$ along Plücker give linear relations between $2$-minors. On the other hand a nondegenerate skew-symmetric form $\Omega$ can over $\mathbb{C}$ broght in block "diagonal" form $diag(H_1,H_2,..., H_m)$ where each $H_i$ is a $2 \times 2$ block of shape $(0,1; -1,0)$. If we fix locally a basis with respect this form, then the condition $Omega(v,w)=0$ is given by vanishing of certain $2$-minors of matrix $(v;w)$. So that fits, thanks for hints!